# Sending mail via Implicit Intent using Gmail with an Image as an attachment in Android?

Tags: android, email, email-attachments

Its simple but creating problem in my application. I am sending **email** using Implicit Intent, having an IMAGE attached as an ATTACHMENT. But creating problem with the below code.

```
File file = new File(path);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Wedding App"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sharing image via email."); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.toString()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Creating crash :

```
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317): Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@417c1fc8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@417c1fc8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1066)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1053)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1047)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:65)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:99)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:53)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
02-22 12:20:47.561: E/ActivityThread(6317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You must call `unregisterReceiver()` on any `receivers` you have registered in your Activity. This will typically be in `onPause()`.

Comment: @Sam-In-TechValens, Try my below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: I think the problem because there is only one application installed in your device so you got exception. If there is multiple application to choose from then you will not get this type of error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("png/image");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
                "mail--id" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/saved_images/MyImage.png"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

and don't forget to add this below permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  implicitly includes 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />, so, it's unnecessary.

Comment: I have added this because might be it's possible that someone is taking image or attachment from internal storage as well. Otherwise it is not necessary.

Comment: So, you didn't read my comment... I wasn't talking about INTERNAL, but EXTERNAL - you added a useless permission. You can just keep WRITE_EXTERNAL and READ_INTERNAL. **READ_EXTERNAL** is useless

Comment: Ohhh, Okay i was not knowing that, sorry for that. And thank you for your valuable comment. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry, my friend. Anyway you have my +1 for your solution. In this case READ_EXTERNAL is useless, not harmful. Just to point it out.

Comment: You deserved it, since yours is a valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
Bitmap b =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Title", null);
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
```

You can download full [Source Code from here](http://www.tarunpuri.com/android-tutorial/post-image-on-facebook-wall-using-intent/)